# error dialog with scrollable area to display big multiline message?

Tags: swing

I need to display error dialog (with standart red cross image) with message and Ok button.
Message is pretty big (like stack-trace) so I need to display it in scrollable area.
Should I write such dialog from scratch or swing contains something that I can reuse?

upd: found unswer myself http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t19012.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to **use [TaskDialog framework](https://github.com/eugener/oxbow)**. You can create all kinds of dialogs including the following:

[image]

The exception dialog can be called via

```
TaskDialogs.showException(e);
```

See [Task Dialog](https://github.com/eugener/oxbow/wiki/Task-Dialog#common-use-cases) for more details

Comment: Agree, but not as simple though. One line in TaskDialog framework: 
TaskDialogs.showException( new Exception());

Comment: Bounds case: I tested TaskDialog 1.3.5 with very long/tall error messages. It does not truncate or scroll the message summary, which can result in a huge window with the **Close** and **Details** controls being off the screen. 
Use case: launch an email client with a URI encoding a large message body. An IOException can be thrown with the entire message body in the exception message.

Comment: Can your please create an issue with code example at http://code.google.com/p/oxbow/issues/list

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this component](http://blue-walrus.com/2015/01/swing-error-dialog-with-exception-displayer/)

[image]

The source code is all there, you just need to copy and paste code. No need to install a framework.